# How to save a many to many model in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following two model class in django.

```
class Rule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rules', null=True, blank=True)
    threshold = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    alert_value = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    is_internal = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'threshold': self.threshold,
            'alert_value': self.alert_value
         }


class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_internal = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rules = models.ManyToManyField(Rule)

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'description': self.description,
            'rules': [r.to_json() for r in self.rules.all()]
        }


    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

Now I have the following code to save a Module object which implicitly contains a rules object in my view.py

```
def create_module(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        module_name = request.POST.get('name')
        module_description = request.POST.get('description')
        rule_ids = request.POST.getlist('rule_id')
        rules = None
        for rule_id in rule_ids:
            try:
                rules = models.Rule.objects.filter(pk__in=rule_id)
            except models.Rule.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        module = models.Module(name=module_name,
                           description=module_description,
                           rules=rules)
        module.save()
```

I get the rules correctly here but when save gets called I get an error

`Exception Type: TypeError at /modules/create/
Exception Value: &#39;rules&#39; is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

How to overcome this when I want to save an object graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rules` is not really a field on the model, it's an entry in a linking table - so it can't be saved until the Module entry exists. Also note that your loop is such that it will never consist of more than one Rules object, because you overwrite the `rules` variable each time. Instead you should simply get all the Rules and add them in one go.

```
module = models.Module(name=module_name,
                       description=module_description)
module.save()
rules = models.Rule.objects.filter(pk__in=rule_ids)
module.rules = rules
```

There's no need to save again after that: assigning to a related queryset does the database operation automatically. Also note that `filter` will not raise a DoesNotExist exception: if there is no matching rule, then there simply won't be an element in the resulting queryset.

Comment: @user567797 make sure, your ``rule_ids`` has some ids in it.

Comment: I don't think rules is getting saved

Comment: Can you print `rules` before the final line in my snippet? Also show how you are displaying the rules later, when you say you get an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

you are overriding the `rules` queryset inside `try` and `filter()` doesnot raise `DoesNotExist` exception btw..

try this:

```
module = models.Module(name=module_name,description=module_description)
module.save()
#first save 'module' and add 'rules' from filter()-result

rules = models.Rule.objects.filter(pk__in=rule_ids)
module.rules = rules 
module.save()
```

[more about how to save m2m](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) in django

Comment: This way you'll get one Module for each rule, which doesn't seem to be what OP wants.